# varnish error: child start failed

Tags: varnish

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

-

```
May  1 14:45:11 server varnishd[1662]: Child start failed: could not open sockets
May  1 14:45:17 server varnishd[1688]: Child start failed: could not open sockets
```

-

Varnish:

```
root@server:~# varnishd -V
varnishd (varnish-2.1.4 SVN )
Copyright (c) 2006-2009 Linpro AS / Verdens Gang AS
```

-

Changes in /etc/default/varnish

```
# Should we start varnishd at boot?  Set to "yes" to enable.
START=yes
```

-
Changed default port number:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"
```

Changes in default.vcl

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
    .max_connections = 800;
```

Start varnish gives me this:

```
root@server:~# service varnish restart
 * Stopping HTTP accelerator varnishd                                    [fail]
 * Starting HTTP accelerator varnishd                                    [ OK ]
```

Server running nginx , php5-fpm, apc, memchache, varnish, mysql, wordpress.

What could be the problem? Thanks for any help.

```
root@server:~# sudo netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2009/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2009/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1271/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1408/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1300/main.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1239/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1408/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1204/memcached
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2009/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1271/sshd
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo netstat -tlnp` to your question?

Comment: added netstat info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have nginx listening on port 80 and you have told Varnish to listen on port 80.  Only one of them can do this for any `IP address:port` combination.

Since you have nginx *also* listening on port 8080 and you have configured Varnish to use port 8080 as the backend, you will probably want to stop nginx listening on port 80 at all.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the case I don't have access to the server now, but I think it should be an easy fix.